# reading exchange mail, address book and calendar in mint 14 nadia

Tags: linux-mint, evolution, exchange

I've heard the only mail client that can be used as ms outlook in mint is evolution. I couldn't find any good web resource regarding this.
I have evolution installed, but I don't see Exchange as an option for server type.
At least I want to be able to read exchange emails, address book and calendars on mint.

Comment: Do you know the version of the Exchange server? Does it offer IMAP access (that would give your access to email, but not to the calendar)?

Comment: Exchange 2007. After I have installed evolution-mapi, I was able to see not only email, but also calendar and global address book :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Evolution you need a special [connector](https://help.gnome.org/users/evolution/stable/exchange-connectors-overview.html.en). A couple of years ago it suffered from very poor code quality (leaking ~1MB per opening a message), it might have been fixed meanwhile though (or it might not).

Another option is [DavMail](http://davmail.sourceforge.net/), which is client agnostic by the way - it exports the Exchange connection as POP3/IMAP4/SMTP interface.

Comment: DavMail looks a kind of cumbersome to me. Though, installing evolution-mapi which is described in page you've referred solved the issue!

Comment: Getting DavMail running is actually pretty straightforward, unless you need to fiddle with certificates on smartcard - then it can get a bit more complicated. But still nothing terribly cumbersome.

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at **evolution-ews** it should be in the repo. It adds Exchange support into evolution and it access mail,contacts and calendar.

`sudo apt-get install evolution-ews` shoud pull it in.

Comment: in this case it added Server Type: Exchange Web Services as an option, which didn't work for me. Is there any plugin (connector?) that adds "Microsoft Exchange" as option?

Comment: Hmm, as oscar says evolution-mapi maybe, Exchange web services works fine for me with Exchange 2007.